# I want to check whether given record is in database or not

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to check whether given record is in database or not. It is showing error "Invalid Column name"

```
 private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC308433;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=adm23");

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select USERNAME from QuizTable where USERNAME=" + UserNameTextbox.Text + "", conn);
        string result =Convert.ToString(sc.ExecuteNonQuery());//I dont know to store the result of query here.Pls help me
        if (result == UserNameTextbox.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Please register");

        conn.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for it, [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is only for insert,update and delete statements, and use Contructor which takes [CommandBehaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum with `SingleRow`, as it should have one row per username:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = sc.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
if(rdr.Read() && (rdr["USERNAME"].ToString() == UserNameTextbox.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
}
```

### SideNote:

You should be using **[parameterized queries](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/)**, currently you are open to **[sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC308433;Initial Catalog=SampleDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=adm23");

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select USERNAME from QuizTable where USERNAME=@USERNAME", conn);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue(@USERNAME,'"+UserNameTextbox.Text+"');
    SqlDataReader dr = sc.ExecuteReader();//Use this line
    if (dr.HasRows)
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Please register");

    conn.Close();


}
```

Comment: This allows SQL injections.This should be used instead,
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(""select USERNAME from QuizTable where USERNAME=@NAME" , conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Value = UserNameTextbox.Text;

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have **USERNAME** column in **QuizTable**.

Here is a complete snippet for you-

> Note: Your column **USERNAME** may create conflict with sql server reserve words. You should change it i.e. USER_NAME or LOGINNAME.

```
try
{
   string userName = UserNameTextbox.Text.Trim();
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Conn String"))
   {
       string sql="select USERNAME from QuizTable where USERNAME=@USERNAME";
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
       {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", userName );

          connection.Open();
          Object IsFound = command.ExecuteScalar();
          connection.Close();


          if (IsFound == null)
          {
              //if not found
          }
          else
          {
              //if found
          }
       }
    }
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the value of the username parameter.

Also, don't use string concatenation to build sql statements. You are way open to injection attacks.

Comment: shhhh, It's a quiz table, let the ones who deserve it change their points.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](http://dotprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-check-data-in-database-in-aspnet.html) , because you use executenonquery () , here i think use ExecuteReader()

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check 'username' in table then 
Plesae try this....

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select USERNAME from QuizTable where USERNAME='" + UserNameTextbox.Text + "'", conn);
```